# Is there away to kill Javascript function with multiple input prompts if "cancel" is clicked on prompt?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function that calculates a physics equation.  The function requires inputs from the user.  For example, if the function requires 3 inputs, the prompt box will appear for the input until each input is given.  Currently, if there are 3 successive prompt boxes and the user clicks cancel on the first one, the following two still pop up requiring the user to click through them.

I am not sure where to start.  I thought of implementing an if..else statement but I'm talking about having close to 100 functions total each with at least 2 or 3 input prompts, and too have an if..else statement for each one seems highly inefficient.

I have searched around on Stack Overflow and other sites but nothing seems to jump out to me to be a logical step in solving this.

If there is a post that addresses this exactly, please link and let me apologize in advance.

Everything works fine with the code, it just seems like the user would be annoyed by having to click out of the function, especially for functions require a higher number of inputs.

HTML code

```
<p><button onclick="finalvelocity()">Final Velocity</button></p>
```

Javascript code

```
function finalvelocity(initialvelocity, acceleration, time)
{
    var initialvelocity = prompt('Please enter the Initial Velocity in Meters per Second');
    var acceleration = prompt('Please enter the Acceleration in Meters per Second Squared');
    var time = prompt('Please enter the Time in Seconds');
    var finalvelocity = Number(initialvelocity) + (Number(acceleration) * Number(time));
    alert('The Final Velocity is found to be: ' + finalvelocity + 'Meters per Second');

}
```

I am hoping there is an attribute I can add to the HTML button for something that will kill the function call if the 'cancel' button is pressed

Comment: check for null, and return.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Lloyd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to work with you code.

```js
// JavaScript code
function finalvelocity(initialvelocity, acceleration, time)
{
    var initialvelocity = prompt('Please enter the Initial Velocity in Meters per Second');
    if(initialvelocity == null) return;
    var acceleration = prompt('Please enter the Acceleration in Meters per Second Squared');
    if(acceleration == null) return;
    var time = prompt('Please enter the Time in Seconds');
    if(time == null) return;
    var finalvelocity = Number(initialvelocity) + (Number(acceleration) * Number(time));
    alert('The Final Velocity is found to be: ' + finalvelocity + 'Meters per Second');

}
```

```html
<!-- HTML Code -->
<p><button onclick="finalvelocity()">Final Velocity</button></p>
```

Here is a simple demo, will keep asking until you click cancel.

```js
function askForStuff() {
  let val = null;
  do {
    val = prompt("enter something");
    console.log(val);
  } while(val != null);
  console.log("done");
}

askForStuff();
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the help.  It appears that I would need to set the if condition to check for null for each variable. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: In this instance yes because you want to exit at any stage.

Comment: This answered my initial question.  Thank you Paul.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 100 inputs, perhaps do not use `prompt()` but, make a form?

```js
function calculateFinalVelocity() {
  var initialvelocity = document.getElementById("initialvelocity").value;
  var acceleration = document.getElementById("acceleration").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;

  var finalvelocity = Number(initialvelocity) + (Number(acceleration) * Number(time));

  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 'The Final Velocity is found to be: ' + finalvelocity + ' m/2';
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="calculateFinalVelocity()">

  <p>
    <label for="initialvelocity">Initial Velocity in m/2<sup>2</sup></label>
    <input id="initialvelocity" type="number" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="acceleration">Acceleration in m/2<sup>2</sup></label>
    <input id="acceleration" type="number" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="time">Time in Seconds</label>
    <input id="time" type="number" />
  </p>

  <button type="submit">Calculate Final Velocity</button>
</form>

<p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: Yeah I actually was interested in this type of submission originally, but to be honest I just started coding and ended up going with button type.

I wish I could create a new question just for this so I can check it as the answer

Comment: @RgSW Not the question, no, but this is an **extremely obvious** [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and a good developer will notice that and help the novice in the right direction. What happens when you make it through 99 `prompt()` and hit cancel by mistake? OP has no notion of an alternative, so simply answering the initial question without context is not helpful.

Comment: @EvanHowington I suspected as much; that's perfectly fine, your question was clear. I'm simply showing _an alternative._

Comment: Thank you @msanford !  I am going to implement this at some point.  You have just stopped me in my tracks because now I need to consider if I want to redo my current code since I have just begun or implement this for more advanced problems.  Thank you for giving me this very insightful information, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @EvanHowington Refresh and see my updated comment above. You should definitely implement a form for at least that reason. My example above is *not exactly* what you should do for hundreds of inputs, but check [this out for some guidance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form). Good luck!

Comment: @msanford thank you, I am reviewing the link you provided now.  I am going to stop my current efforts and replicate my code with the form version and compare, I'm pretty sure I will like the form better, but I need to play with them both side by side.  

my implementation of this is live at [link](http://aethyn.com)  I am looking at over 100 different functions I am going to have to define so figuring out how I am going to proceed at this early stage will be best.

Answer (score 1):

The `prompt` function returns `null` when cancel is pressed, so you can actually check if the returned values are `null` and then kill the function with a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way would be to put the prompt text in an array and then loop through it.

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnzujx7L/

Code:

```
var promptArr = [
    "Please enter the Initial Velocity in Meters per Second",
  "Please enter the Acceleration in Meters per Second Squared",
  "Please enter the Time in Seconds"
];
var values = [];

for (var t = 0; t < promptArr.length; t++) {
    var k = prompt(promptArr[t]);
  if (k == null) {
    break;
  }
  else {
    values.push(k);
  }
}

if (values.length === 3) {
    var finalvelocity = Number(values[0]) + (Number(values[1]) * Number(values[2]));
  alert(finalvelocity);
}
```